# how to convert variable module shelve?

Tags: python, python-3.x

please help convert the variable "fileNameClean" so that you can open the file via the module "shelve"

```
import shelve

fileName = 'C:/Python33/projects/DVD_LIST/p3_dvd_list_shelve_3d_class_edit_menubar/data.dir'
print('___', fileName)
str = fileName.split('/')[-1]
print('--', str)
fileNameClean = str.split('.')[0:-1]
print(fileNameClean)                #['data']

db = shelve.open(fileNameClean)     #open error
```

Comment: You get a list: say `db = shelve.open(fileNameClean[0])` instead

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`os.path`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html) module to produce a clean path:

```
import os.path

fileName = 'C:/Python33/projects/DVD_LIST/p3_dvd_list_shelve_3d_class_edit_menubar/data.dir'

fileNameClean = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(fileName))[0]
db = shelve.open(fileNameClean)
```

Your code also produced a base name minus the extension, but you returned a *list* by using a slice (from index 0 until but not including the last element). You could have used `fileNameClean[0]`, but using the `os.path` module makes sure you catch edgecases in path handling too.

You probably want to make sure you don't use a relative path here either. To open the `shelve` file in the same directory as the current script or module, use `__file__` to get an absolute path to the parent directory:

```
here = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
db = shelve.open(os.path.join(here, fileNameClean))
```